# How to get property value from ionic 2 storage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a Promise which i used to get the stored data of in an Ionic storage

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this._storage
.get("user")
.then(value => value)));
```

and it prints out {"user-profile":"user","acct_no":"1234567890"}

how do i get the property value of acct_no? which will be 1234567890

Answer (score 2):

Just correct your code to this...

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this._storage
.get("user")
.then(value => value.acct_no)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `return new Promise ...` does not make much sense as `storage.get` already returns a promise. You could just do `return this._storage
.get("user");` which would have the same effect. To get the `acct_no` property, just access it in the callback:

```
this._storage
    .get("user")
    .then(value => {
        console.log(value.acct_no);
    });
```